# Prove $x^3 + x +1 = 0$ has no rational solutions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

> Use a suitable method to prove that there is no rational solutions to the equation:
> $$x^3 + x + 1 = 0$$ or give a counter-example to show otherwise.

I tried to do this question via polynomial factorization and contradiction.

Let $$f(x) = x^3 + x + 1 = 0$$

By polynomial factorisation by assuming there is a root $r$,

$$f(x) = (x-r)(x^2 + xr + r^2 + 1)$$

$$f(x) = (x^3 + rx^2 + xr^2 + x - rx^2 - xr^2 - r^3 - r)$$

$$f(x) = (x^3 + x - r^3 - r)$$

Comparing the coefficients:

$$r^3 - r = 1$$

From this, we can assume that root $r$ exists, and hence, we have proven by contradiction that a root exists.

I want to ask if my proof is correct.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here, but how do you know that the polynomial factorisation must be $f(x) = (x - r)(x^2 + xr + r^2 + 1)$? I also don't understand your final statement; I don't know why $r^3 - r = 1$ means that no root exists (indeed a root definitely does exist; it just isn't rational).

Comment: @TheoBendit with $r^3 - r = 1$, it shows that a root exists. That is why I thought I proved by contradiction to the statement that $x^3 + x + 1 = 0$ has no solution.

Comment: @WeitingChen: But $x^3+x+1=0$ *does* have solutions—it just doesn't have rational solutions. Where in your proof have you used the fact that $r$ is rational to obtain a contradiction?

Comment: You have this equation that, assuming your previous statements are correct (and I remain unconvinced that they are), is a condition that any root $r$ of $x^3 + x + 1$ must satisfy. But, this doesn't mean that there is such an $r$, just that if there were one, it would have to satisfy this condition. Now you just have a new polynomial equation $r^3 - r - 1 = 0$. How do you even know that there is a solution to this equation?

Comment: @TheoBendit So what you're saying is that I need to further prove that $r^3 -r -1 = 0$ actually has a rational solution for me to satisfy this contradiction proof (assuming that rational root(s) actually exist)?

Comment: @WeitingChen No, there's a deeper problem. Even if you show that $r^3 - r - 1 = 0$ has a rational solution, there are still problems. First, where is the contradiction? If you have proven that there are rational solutions, that they have to be rational roots of $r^3 - r - 1$, and that such rational roots exist, then so far there's no problem. If you showed no rational roots of $r^3 - r - 1$ existed, then that would be a contradiction! Also, just because rational roots of $r^3 - r - 1$ exist doesn't mean that they automatically satisfy $x^3 + x + 1 = 0$; your logic flows forwards not backwards.

Comment: @WeitingChen: Neither of the equations you wrote actually has a rational root, but every cubic polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root.  Your approach never uses rationality of $r$, and never reaches a contradiction.

Comment: By the way, not only your "proof" proves nothing, but there is another mistake: by comparing coefficients, you should get $-r^3-r=1$, that is $r^3+r+1=0$ (which is of course what you assumed) and **not** $r^3-r=1$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129031/discussion-on-question-by-weiting-chen-prove-x3-x-1-0-has-no-rational-so).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(I do think the question is interesting: not because it's particularly insightful, but because it has a flaw commonly committed by newcomers)*

Your proof is not correct, for two reasons:

- A minor computational error, that gives the illusion that you found out something.
- A major logical error.

Let's start with the minor one:

From $f(x) = x^3+x+1=(x-r)(x^2 + xr + r^2 + 1)=x^3 + x - r^3 - r$, you write that, by comparing coefficients, you get $r^3 - r = 1$. It's wrong.

Actually, by comparing coefficients, you have

$$x^3+x+1=x^3+x-r^3-r$$
$$1=-r^3-r$$
$$r^3+r+1=0$$

---

Now, the major problem. You would like to find a proof by contradiction.
Initially, you want to prove that the polynomial $x^3+x+1$ has no rational root. That is, any complex number $r$ such that $r^3+r+1=0$ satisfies $r\notin \Bbb Q$.

To find a proof by contradiction, you would have to assume $r$ is a root, **and** $r$ is rational, and find a contradiction.

Here, you only assumed that $r$ is a root. There is no contradiction to be found, as any polynomial with complex coefficients and degree $n>0$ has exactly $n$ complex roots. It **has** roots, hence there will be no contradiction assuming it has a root.

With your assumption, and after correcting the little computational mistake, you find out that $r^3+r+1=0$. But that's the assumption! You assumed $r$ is a root of $x^3+x+1$, i.e. exactly that $r^3+r+1=0$, and you find out that the same equality is true.

---

So your proof by contradiction in this current state is moot. It's still possible to do it though, using the idea behind the more general [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Assume $r$ is a rational root of $x^3+x+1$. That is, there are coprime integers $a$ and $b$ such that $r=a/b$ and $r^3+r+1=0$. The important fact, here, is that a rational number is the quotient of two **coprime** integers.

Then:

$$\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac ab+1=0$$

$$a^3+ab^2+b^3=0$$

Now, we have easily a contradiction: since the sum is zero and two of the three terms are divisible by $b$, then the third must also be divisible by $b$. However, per our assumtpions, it's coprime to $b$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: (+1) This answer pinpoints the OP's specific point of confusion. Analogously, in the proof by contradiction that there is no rational number $\dfrac{a}{b}$ such that $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=2}$, we *must* use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are integers at some point in the proof. If we didn't, then the proof would be faulty, as $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt2}{1}\right)^2=2$.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to see.

Comment: The following meta-commentary was in the original version of this answer "(I do think the question is interesting: not because it's particularly insightful, but because it has a flaw commonly committed by newcomers)".  Please note that Question are for questions, and Answers are for answers.  Please do not use these spaces for meta commentary (leaving a comment is fine, or post it on meta).

Comment: @Xander, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34028/two-downvotes-and-one-delete-vote-for-answering-a-question? seemed to settle matters to everyone's satisfaction – except yours.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut From your deleted meta question: "And additionally a comment removed two times from the question without clear motivation." Regarding deletion, I counted 5 removals, from Xander and myself; I don't know if these are the deletions to which you refer. Just so you know, I fully support all 5 deletions. Xander removed two brusque, useless replies from him then from me. He also warned me about another of my comments, which I then agreed stepped over the line, and I promised to delete (which I did). Xander then promptly removed the warning and my response.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ok, thanks. Actually I meant the edits on this answer, I wasn't aware of those deleted comments.